# Check boxes and Database does not work

Tags: php, javascript, database, checkbox

So I've been trying to get the user_id of users if their check box is clicked and save it to the database, but my code doesn't seem to work.

```
$invites = $_POST["invite"];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO group_members (fan_id, group_id) VALUES ('$invites',     '$group_id')") or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($friends)) {
                echo "<div id=\"groupFanBox\"><a href=\"profile.php?id=" . $row['user_id'] . "\">" . $row['full_name'] . "</a><br><input type=\"checkbox\"value=" . $row['user_id'] . " name=\"invite[]\"></br></div>";
                echo $row['user_id'];
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: Where are you having problems?

Comment: IDK If its a typo, but make sure you put a space between `checkbox"` and `value` in your input tag: `type="checkbox" value="....` That will cause an error

Answer (score 1):

Insert queries don't return result sets, so there's nothing for `mysql_fetch_array()` to work on. Perhaps you wanted a SELECT query instead:

```
SELECT user_id, full_name
FROM group_members
```

Comment: i need to put the value of the check box, in this case, $row['user_id'], into my database. I need to use insert.

Comment: i have a select function, i just didnt bother to post it.. the problem is with insert

Answer (score 0):

You try to store an array into your database!

You have to perform the insertion for every checkbox:

```
foreach($_POST['invites'] as $fanId) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO group_members (fan_id, group_id) VALUES ('" . intval($fanId) . "', '" . intval($groupId . "')") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

I asume that your insert statement is the real question, the while loop is only to show how you create the checkboxes :-) If not, my answer meight be wrong ;-)

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to both see what is failing, and deal with your code later down the line, is to output the html you want with php without the echo statements.

So this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($friends)) {
                echo "<div id=\"groupFanBox\"><a href=\"profile.php?id=" . $row['user_id'] . "\">" . $row['full_name'] . "</a><br><input type=\"checkbox\"value=" . $row['user_id'] . " name=\"invite[]\"></br></div>";
                echo $row['user_id'];
```

becomes this:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($friends)){
//close your php before the loop ends
?>
<div id="groupFanBox">
<a href="profile.php?id=<?php print $row['user_id'];?>"><?php print $row['full_name'];?></a>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php print $row['user_id'];?>" name="invite[]">
<br/>
</div>";
<?php //then close the loop afterwards
}
?>
```

Readability aside, I think the issue you're having comes from your naming of the checkbox.`name='invites[]'` is, I do not believe, equivalent to the post `$_POST['invites']` you are attempting to retrieve. drop the brackets to `name='invites'` and see if it works.